# Change background color from js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-color

I would set the background color of an element by onclick javascript function.
My code is:

```
function changeBg( el ) {
    if( $( el ).css( "background-color" ) === "rgb(255,255,0)" ) {
        $( el ).css( "background-color", "red" );
    }
    else {
        $( el ).css( "background-color", "rgb(255,255,0)" );
    }
}
```

This code works for change the default background color to yellow (rgb(255, 255,0)) but it doesn't work from yellow to red. The first condition is always skipped

Comment: I would recommend putting the jQuery object in a variable. Rather than creating a new jQuery object on each line.

Comment: try to capture value, before compare, will be different. Because is parsing to hexadecimal, and your comparation is RGBA

Comment: I tried to print the typeof and the value of the element  background color and return String rgb(255,255,0)

Comment: As you're comparing strings, try putting spaces in between the RGB values as that's likely to be the issue `$( el ).css( "background-color" ) === "rgb(255, 255, 0)"`

Comment: Are you sure its not returning "rgb(255, 255, 0)" with the spaces

Comment: you want to toggle between 2 colors only?

Comment: Thanks, it works. The issue was the spaces

Comment: If you are toggling between two colors you can use `toggle function` in jquery. It is good practice.

Answer (score 7):

For more better way use with `toggleClass()` instead of color value matching with in dom

```js
function changeBg(el) {
  $(el).toggleClass('red')
}
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
button{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeBg(this)">change</button>
```

Comment: inline js / css caused by js needs to stop :D this should be used^^ :)

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('redColor');
    })
})
```

```css
button {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.redColor {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.container').on('click',function(){
  var el = ".container";
  if ($(el).css("background-color") === "rgb(255, 255, 0)") {
    $(el).css("background-color", "red");
  } else {
    $(el).css("background-color", "rgb(255, 255, 0)");
  }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  Test
</div>
```